# Wordpress remove or override action "template_redirect" from another plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin is using a function called with action:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', array( &$this, 'maybe_setup_cart' ), 100 );
```

I need to remove this action in my plugin, as it is causing unwanted effects.

I have tried creating an action before it in plugin construct, to override it:

```
add_action('template_redirect', array( &$this, 'maybe_setup_cart' ), 98);
```

In it i am also trying to remove the action:

```
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_setup_cart', 100 );
```

This is also not working.
How can i disable the action from another plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy function shared here:
https://github.com/herewithme/wp-filters-extras/blob/master/wp-filters-extras.php

Next simply do

```
remove_filters_with_method_name( 'template_redirect', 'maybe_setup_cart', 100 );
```

I tried and It works :)

Thanks